# What is a cost effective solution to store pdf files on cloud when I am using AWS infrastructure?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage

I am specifically looking to host it on AWS infrastructure. I have already been using AWS S3 and Postgres. Will any of these serve the purpose without costing too much for the storage.

Comment: What's wrong with storing the PDF files in S3? You should continue storing the files there, and only store metadata about the files in your database. Any database will work just fine for that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I was expecting a solution cheaper than S3 to store these pdf docs since I am not much worried about the latency incurred during querying it.

Comment: There isn't anything cheaper than S3.

Answer (score 1):

Much depend on total pdf files size. If total pdf files size is miniscule compared to your total database size then go for database but if it is sizable compared to database size then opt for AWS S3. In that scenario, you can evaluate and set object lifecycle policy based on usage. Also you can choose appropriate storage class like standard or Standard-IA or use intelligent_tiering to further reduce cost.

Adding another AWS product will add another cost, so evaluate if it can be done with Postgres only.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

S3 will always be a cheaper option than a database. To answer your question, continue dumping the PDF files in S3.